# Which applications on Mac AppStore build HTML5 (drag and drop)?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, mac-appstore

Which applications on Mac AppStore build HTML5 (drag and drop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are looking for with HTML5, one app that helps with creation is [Hype, which is available in the Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/hype/id436931759?mt=12). This looks mostly like it would help with animations (like you may have previously with Flash), but other HTML features are there too.